# Cinnamon: Can't configure applets

Tags: linux, debian, cinnamon, applet

I'm working with Debian using Cinnamon as my desktop env, and I have recently been having tons of problems with it. First, I was having an issue where, after logging in, everything would be black, and the only program I could run was my terminal emulator, from which I could run other applications, but I couldn't close or minimize them. I fixed this by forcing the command `cinnamon --replace` to run at startup, which is a very shoddy fix.

Now, I'm having the issue where I wanted to configure an applet (basically get into the menu editor of Cinnamenu), but when I right click on the applet and click the 'configure' option on the menu, nothing happens. This also happens for every other applet I have installed, which is a problem.

Comment: Is this a Debian distro/spin that came bundled with Cinnamon or did you try to manually add/change to Cinnamon?  Did it previously work and then stopped working, or is this a new installation that has never worked?  Have you verified that all of the hardware requirements are met and that Debian either supports your hardware or you have added all necessary drivers (e.g., the non-free iso)?  Has a previous installation of Debian Cinnamon worked on your system?  Did you verify the iso checksum?  Did the problems start after any updates?

Comment: Which version & release of Debian are you using?  If Stable, have you verified that all dependencies have been met?  If Testing, why use Cinnamon with Debian?  Ubuntu is Debian Testing with additional testing and polish.  Mint is Ubuntu with additional testing and polish.  Cinnamon is Mint's flagship DE and is tightly integrated.  Mint will give you the cleanest, most stable Cinnamon implementation on a Debian Testing base.

Comment: @fixer1234 I've been using this distro for several months with no problems. It came prepackaged with the option to install several DEs, including Cinnamon, which I chose. The hardware is fine, all the drivers were installed and working fine. The problems started when I installed python3-gi using `pip` instead of `apt`, which broke Jupyter and a few other programs which depended on it. After fixing that (by uninstalling and reinstalling python entirely), my problems started.

Comment: However, I think I'm just going to back up and reinstall with GNOME or XFCE because there are several other things I broke on this install separate from Cinnamon.

Comment: @fixer1234 I was using Cinnamon because I was familiar with it because I used to use Mint back in high school. Now that I am more experienced with Linux, I think it is time to switch DEs.